# array_intersect Inside multidimensional-array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

i have an multidimensioanl array which can increase based on user input.i want to do array_intersect inside the array to get the common values between the key.

like example

```
Array ( [php] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 51 [2] => 116 [3] => 171 [4] => 215 [5] => 219 [6] => 229 [7] => 247 [8] => 316 ) [java] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 16 [2] => 19 [3] => 24 [4] => 25 [5] => 26 [6] => 29 [7] => 31 [8] => 33 [9] => 34 [10] => 35 [11] => 36 [12] => 37 [13] => 40 [14] => 45 [15] => 49 [16] => 51 ) )
```

expected output should be like (36,51)

and this is i am able to get it

via this,

```
$intersected_array = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array);
```

but if my array had a third key also which doesnot had a common value in all three of them

like

```
Array ( [php] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 51 [2] => 116 [3] => 171 [4] => 215 [5] => 219 [6] => 229 [7] => 247 [8] => 316 ) [java] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 16 [2] => 19 [3] => 24 [4] => 25 [5] => 26 [6] => 29 [7] => 31 [8] => 33 [9] => 34 [10] => 35 [11] => 36 [12] => 37 [13] => 40 [14] => 45 [15] => 49 [16] => 51 ) [ajax] => Array ( [0] => 91 [1] => 110 [2] => 113 [3] => 172 ) )
```

then it is throwing me  output as the result of the key having max values. in this case it will return me all the values of `java` key.

but my expected output is `0`. please help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact code you're using. Recreating your array and running the code shown returns an empty array on my machine just as you would expect.

Comment: It working fine for me and GreenRiver. Are you sure it's not a simple oversight, like you didn't pass in the variable you think you did?

Comment: thank you all for your support, it's is working fine, it was my mistake in the code which was leading me into diff output. i am really sorry to bother u all for my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copyed you example and for me it works:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'php' => array(
        36,
        51,
        116,
        171,
        215,
        219,
        229,
        247,
        316,
    ),
    'java' => array(
        14,
        16,
        19,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        29,
        31,
        33,
        34,
        35,
        36,
        37,
        40,
        45,
        49,
        51,
    ),
    'ajax' => array(
        91,
        110,
        113,
        172,
    ),
);

$intersected_array = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$array);

print_r($intersected_array);

// RESULT: "Array ( ) "
```

Please copy exactly this code and tell me your output.

Comment: Ok and where is now your problem?

Comment: He mentioned it in the question "expected output should be like (36,51)" you didnt seen it?????@GreenRover

Comment: But ajax dont include 36 and 51. You like to get all numbers that are in more then one array but not have to be in all arrays?

Comment: You wrote with only "java*" and "php" you like to get 36, 51. Thats right, this is what will be returened without the "ajax" array. But if you also have the ajxa array, the result is an emty array. But i still not understand what you expecting.

Comment: I also ran the same code and got an empty array, which is expected since there is no point of intersection between all 3 sub-arrays.  @User - You should take a breath and re-read the OP's question. he says he expects the result to be 0, which it won't be, but I'm assuming he means "zero intersects".  The code is fine, so something else is going wrong

Comment: @Anthony,u guys are correct, code is working fine, i had a bug in my complete code set. sorry to bother u all..